# SESSION_COOKIE_NAME error in Flask when logging in after a while

Tags: python, flask, web, session, session-cookies

Until recently, everything was fine, but now my site constantly gives "SESSION_COOKIE_NAME" and 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modified' errors. But the instresting is if i change the code and it doesn't matter how the error disappears for a while. Please help knowledgeable people

Here are most important part of code:

```
import os
import plotly.express as px
import cs50
import pandas as pd
import json
import plotly
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, jsonify, url_for
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from datetime import datetime
from plotly.graph_objs import Figure, Scatter

from helpers import apology, login_required, lookup, usd

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

load_dotenv()

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_USE_SIGNER"] = True
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.urandom(24)
app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_NAME"] = 'session_cookie_name'

Session(app)

# I'm also using part of code like this in my app
    session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]
    # or
    user_id = session["user_id"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run
```

And here the errors logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2527, in wsgi_app
    ctx.push()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 375, in push
    self.session = session_interface.open_session(self.app, self.request)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_session/sessions.py", line 329, in open_session
    sid = request.cookies.get(app.session_cookie_name)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 287, in session_cookie_name
    warnings.warn(
DeprecationWarning: 'session_cookie_name' is deprecated and will be removed in Flask 2.3. Use 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME' in 'app.config' instead.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1847, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2343, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_session/sessions.py", line 353, in save_session
    if session.modified:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modified'
```

What I just did not try and deleted it altogether and changed the names. This problem occurs after some time after logging into the account, when trying to search the site, it simply gives this error instead of a POST request.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.